# Erlang: check duplicate elements

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I'm trying to make function that read `{Jid, Text}` and check if it's already in the list return `true` else if it's not this function should append it to the list then return `false`

What I'm doing is :

```
new_seen() -> [{"user@domain.tld", "hello"}].

check({Jid, Text}) ->
    Term = {Jid, Text},
    case lists:member(Term, new_seen()) of
        true -> true;
        false ->
            %% here I want to add {Jid, Text} to new_seen() list.
            false
    end.
```

Simple example :

```
check({"us1@domain.tld", "hi"}).
%% here should appened {"us1@domain.tld", "hi"} to the list and return false.


%% if I run function again :
check({"us1@domain.tld", "hi"}).

%% here should return True cuz {"us1@domain.tld", "hi"} in the list.
```

I want to use it with ejabberd to check if duplicate inserted messages.

Comment: What are your needs? What data do you need to hold in that list? Is it a big database? You will probably want to check [Erlang ETS](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) or [Process Dictionary](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id87983)

Comment: @A.Sarid yes it's a big database. yes but I shouldn't use ets or process dictionary cuz there is soo much data. I also asked here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958767/erlang-check-duplicate-inserted-elements

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: It seems like you got your answer in your previous question.  So, why not to use ETS for your database? It should exactly fit for big databases.

Comment: @A.Sarid I edit my question.

Comment: @A.Sarid is this true ? http://paste.ubuntu.com/18170115/

Comment: You should mark a answer as correct or respond why it is not correct, @Mr. zero

Answer (score 2):

Have you also checked different databases like mnesia (Kev/Value Storage)? Maybe they can 
Seems like a [map](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html) could help you. You can access values for a specific key. You should also check [learnyousomeerlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/maps) for this.

If you require a list, just append the element. With your code:

```
check({Jid, Text}) ->
    Term = {Jid, Text},
    case lists:member(Term, new_seen()) of
        true -> true;
        false ->
            %% here I want to add {Jid, Text} to new_seen() list.
            NewList = [Term|new_seen()]
    end,
NewList.
```

You have to return the new list and save it somewhere else, since you cannot update the list in your new_seen() function.
If you really need to return true, put this to the last line: `{true, NewList}` which returns the tuple with true and the new list.

Comment: True, but i guess that if he needs a database, he should add this list as another parameter to the function: `check({Jid, Text}, Database)`. and use `Database` instead of calling `new_seen()`.